# How to show containerview in viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, button, containers, viewcontroller

I need to show containerview in viewcontroller, so i have taken one viewcontroller and designed and in that i have taken one containerview below to the buttons view

given `containerview` constraints: below to the buttonview

```
  top = buttonview.bottom 10, leading, trailing, bottom = 0
```

[image]

there are two buttons indicates with green line.. initially i am in the "viewproposalvc" with red colour button.. here if i click gray colour button then i need to show containerview

here the `viewproposalvc` code:

```
 class ViewProposalVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var postId: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateNavigationBar(with: "View Proposal")
    containerView.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func grayBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    containerView.isHidden = false

 let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerVC") as? ContainerVC
  vc.serviceId = self.viewproposalData?.result?.posted_services?.id
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func redBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    containerView.isHidden = true
    postedServicesCall()
}
}
```

this is containervc code:

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

but here containervc not coming below to the buttonsview.. its coming in separate viewcontroller, why?

**o/p of containervc**: i dont want separate viewcontroller.. i need `containervc` to show below to the buttonsview of the `viewproposalvc`

first time i am working with container views, please do help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because you are calling

```
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

ContainerView is just a generic UIView with an embedded segue, that is triggered from viewDidLoad of the hosted VC. If you need to do additional setup of that VC I suggest making an var on ViewProposalVC and making desired changes from there.

as in

```
class ViewProposalVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var postId: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondaryController: UIViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateNavigationBar(with: "View Proposal")
    containerView.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func grayBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    containerView.isHidden = false
    self.secondaryController.serviceId = self.viewproposalData?.result?.posted_services?.id

}
```

Comment: here what is `secondaryController` outlet

Comment: @swift your embedded VC I guess in your case looks like ServiceVC which is the embeded segue in your image although looks like you are trying to push ContainerVC I'm not real sure. Your containerView just has an embedded segue to a view controller. That is what the view presents as a view.